# Cant get hue value of pixel in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am converting image to HSV from RGB, but I am unable to extract the hue part at a specific pixel..
I tried three codes, non of them working.

First way (error coming in "hue.at(j,i)"):
`int detectHue(Mat & result, int x_start, int x_stop, int y_start, int y_stop, Scalar & color){
    Mat hsv;
    cvtColor(result, hsv, CV_RGB2HSV);
    vector<Mat> channels;
    split(hsv, channels);
    Mat hue = channels[0];
    int h_trail_x = result.cols, h_trail_y = result.rows;
    bool loop = true;
    for(int j = y_start; j < y_stop && loop; j+=2){
        for(int i = x_start; i < x_stop && loop; i+=2){
            if(hue.at<uchar>(j,i) >= 60 && hue.at<uchar>(j,i) <= 120){
                h_trail_x = i;
                h_trail_y = j;
                loop = false;
            }
        }
    }
    // do something
}`

Second way (error coming in "hsv.at(j,i)"):
`int detectHue(Mat & result, int x_start, int x_stop, int y_start, int y_stop, Scalar & color){
    Mat hsv;
    cvtColor(result, hsv, CV_RGB2HSV);
    int h_trail_x = result.cols, h_trail_y = result.rows;
    bool loop = true;
    for(int j = y_start; j < y_stop && loop; j+=2){
        for(int i = x_start; i < x_stop && loop; i+=2){
            int hue = hsv.at<Vec3b>(j,i).val[0];
            if(hue >= 60 && hue <= 120){
                h_trail_x = i;
                h_trail_y = j;
                loop = false;
            }
        }
    }
    //do something
}`

Third way (a random error occurs at "hsv.col(j).row(i).data[2]". The code runs sometimes, and fails other times): 
`int detectHue(Mat & result, int x_start, int x_stop, int y_start, int y_stop, Scalar & color){
    Mat hsv;
    cvtColor(result, hsv, CV_RGB2HSV);
    int h_trail_x = result.cols, h_trail_y = result.rows;
    bool loop = true;
    for(int j = y_start; j < y_stop && loop; j+=2){
        for(int i = x_start; i < x_stop && loop; i+=2){
            //int hue = hsv.at<Vec3b>(j,i).val[0];
            int hue = hsv.col(j).row(i).data[0];
            int sat = hsv.col(j).row(i).data[1];
            int lum = hsv.col(j).row(i).data[2];
            if(hue >= 60 && hue <= 120 && sat > 20 && lum < 100){
                cout<<"found\n";
                h_trail_x = i;
                h_trail_y = j;
                loop = false;
            }
        }
    }
    // do something
}`

The Error Message is: `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= _rowRange.start && _rowRange.start <= _rowRange.end && _rowRange.end <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 284`

I am checking x_start > 0, etc... Checking the bounds.
Input source of image: WebCam.
Image Type(`Mat result`): CV_8UC3

Please correct me..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your third version you have row and col swapped, it should be `hsv.col(i).row(j)` I guess, but your first two versions look right to me, so I'll have a closer look.

Comment: can you pleas post the error message?

Comment: can you add those lines in the beginning of the function: `if(x_start<0)x_start=0; if(x_stop>result.cols)x_stop=result.cols; if(y_start<0)y_start=0; if(y_stop>result.rows)y_stop=result.rows;` please?

Comment: your first version works for me... if you are certain that you used legal x/y values (see previous comment), how did you capture the image? what is those images type? For a 8UC3 input image it should work!

Comment: Error Message: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= _rowRange.start && _rowRange.start <= _rowRange.end && _rowRange.end <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 284

Comment: I am checking x_start > 0, etc...

Comment: Input source: WebCam. Type: CV_8UC3

Comment: you need proper bounds checking for your x_start,y_start, etc.

Comment: Have done that! Checked the bounds..